# How to sort with elasticsearch?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, elasticsearch, tire

I am trying to make methods for sorting `desc` and `asc`. I am using rails, tire gem and elasticsearch. I am trying to figure out what sort params I can send in the URL

So I have defined in the search-block that it is sorting the result desc order.

```
sort { by :price, "desc"}
```

When a user search for apartments in: **new-york** the result is sort desc order.

The search query/URL looks like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/apartmens?utf8&query=newyork
```

Why cant I add a sort-params in the url, like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/apartmens?utf8&query=newyork&sort=asc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it would be something like this.

```
params[:sort] ||= 'asc'
Tire.search('apartmens') do |s| 
   s.query do |q|
     q.string 'newyork'
   end
   s.sort { by :__FIELD_YOU_WANT_TO_SORT_, params[:sort]}
end
```

Comment: Mike is right. SHUMAcupcake, have a look at Tire's integration tests, https://github.com/karmi/tire/blob/master/test/integration/sort_test.rb

Comment: For some reason, sort by a date field is not sorting. Its working for all the other types (integers and floats). Is there a specific syntax which should be used when it is a date field ?