# Why won't Elasticsearch sort my records in descending order?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch

I have a an index containing documents with a `purchased_at`. Its mapping is:

```
"purchased_at" : {
  "format" : "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis",
  "type" : "date"
}
```

Documents contain field values in this format: `"2013-06-21T11:07:07.000Z"`. [The docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_sorting.html#_sorting_by_field_values) say about sorting:

> The `_score` is not calculated, because it is not being used for sorting.

This is a pretty good indicator if my `sort` parameter is used or not. I'm using the `elasticsearch` gem in version 2.0.0. What's working is sorting in ascending order:

```
MyModel.search("original_id:#{uniq_original_id}", sort: 'purchased_at')
```

What doesn't work:

```
# syntax documented here:
# https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-rails/blob/15761247f3e99654bda946a178e50b5365414b59/elasticsearch-model/test/integration/active_record_pagination_test.rb#L106
MyModel.search("original_id:#{uniq_original_id}", sort: [{purchased_at: 'desc'}])

# syntax used here:
# https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-rails/blob/15761247f3e99654bda946a178e50b5365414b59/elasticsearch-persistence/examples/notes/application.rb#L114
MyModel.search("original_id:#{uniq_original_id}", sort: [{purchased_at: {order: 'desc'}}])

# syntax used here:
# https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-rails/blob/15761247f3e99654bda946a178e50b5365414b59/elasticsearch-rails/lib/rails/templates/searchable.rb#L132
MyModel.search("original_id:#{uniq_original_id}", sort: {purchased_at: 'desc'})
```

Needless to say, I'm confused. How can I sort the field in descending order?

Comment: Can you see in the log, which search request is actually generated and executed? This could help, why the search is not working correctly.

Comment: Seems to be a known issue: https://github.com/ankane/searchkick/pull/639

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried
"sort": {
  "purchased_at": 
  { "order": "desc"  }
}

PS. I cant comment yet that's why I posted this as an answer

Comment: Do you think it's an issue with stringified vs. symbolized keys?

Comment: I not actually sure how you do it on ruby cause I've been using elasticsearch on java. Hopefully this one can help you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30030264/ordering-elasticsearch-results-elasticsearch-rails-gem-rails